# Runge Kutta stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am facing a problem solving a ODE with a Runge-Kutta 4th order method:

The expression in order to solve is :

\begin{equation}
Ay^{''}+By^{'}+Cy= Cu
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y =OUTPUT
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u=INPUT
\end{equation}

We are using a sample time of 0.01s (with 0.001s sample time it does work), but the solver with some combinations of A,B and C does not converge. Then, we would like to know these combinations of A,B and C that make the method fail before start to using it.

Thanks in advance.

Case of study 1 (This crashes)
$A=1.039\cdot10^3$
$B=5\cdot10^5$
$C=1.55\cdot10^7$

Case of study 2 (This works)
$A=7.93\cdot10^3$
$B=5\cdot10^5$
$C=1.55\cdot10^5$

Comment: Can you provide sample values for $A, B, C$ that work and that don't work? Sounds like stability issue.

Comment: You should take a look at the conditions for A, B and C. In MATLAB you can use cond(A) or condest(A). If they are too large, RK will run into problems.

Comment: Are $A, B, C$ matrices or numbers?

Comment: **A**,**B** and **C** are numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is [stiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). I recommend you to take a look at the book *Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II. Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems* by E. Hairer and G. Wanner. For stiff problems you need either an explicit method with small timestep or some stiff-stable implicit method.

To determine whether and RK method with timestep $\Delta t$ is applicable to some problem, you need to know two things:

- Eigenvalues of your problem
- Region of stability of the method used

The eigenvalues of your problems can be easily found from characteristic equation
$$
A \lambda^2 + B\lambda + C = 0
$$
and that are
$$
\lambda_1 \approx -447.927, \lambda_2 \approx -33.305
$$
for the unstable case and
$$
\lambda_{1,2} \approx -31.5259 \pm 30.9955i
$$
for the stable one.

For a method to be stable, all the values $z_i = \lambda_i \Delta t$ must lie in the method's stability region, which for RK4 is given by
$$
\left|1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6} + \frac{z^4}{24}\right| \leq 1
$$
Here's an image of the stability region for RK4

[image: RK4 stability region]

You can see, that for $\Delta t = 0.001$ every $z_i$ lies in the stability region and for $\Delta t = 0.01$ the $\lambda_1 \approx -448$ gives $z_1 \approx -4.4$ which lies outside.

Comment: **Thank you very much!** This is exactly the explanation that I was looking for. I knew that it had something to do with the convergence region of the method but I was not able to figure out the relation between the eigenvalues and the time step.